# AdonisJs Mysql Relationship is not working properly! Giving empty array whenever I try to fetch from database

Tags: mysql, node.js, adonis.js

Currently I'm learning AdonisJs and Mysql. I was practicing demo pilot project like facebook status / comment system. Meanwhile I was trying to understand the relationship of mysql database. But Whenever I want to fetch all the comments associated with one particular status, the status controller produces empty comments array. I don't know where exactly the problem is.

Here is my Status Model

```
const Model = use('Model')

class Status extends Model {

    comments() {
        return this.hasMany('App/Models/Comment', 'id', 'status_id')
    }


}
```

Here is my Comment model

```
class Comment extends Model {

    users() {
        return this.belongsTo('App/Models/User')
    }
}
```

Here is my Status Controller

```
const Status = use('App/Models/Status')
const Comment = use('App/Models/Comment')

class StatusController {

    async showAll({ request, response }){
        return await Status.query()
                            .with('comments')
                            .fetch()
        //return Comment.query().fetch()
    }

    async addStatus({ request, response, auth }) {
        let data = request.all()
        const user_id = await auth.user.id
        data.user_id = user_id
        const status = await Status.create(data)
        return status
    }
    async addComments({ request, response }){}
}

module.exports = StatusController
```

statusController showAll methods returns outputs like this:(comments array is empty where it shouldn't be)

```
[
{
"id": 1,
"user_id": "2",
"status": "Hello Everyone ...",
"created_at": "2019-04-09 17:05:01",
"updated_at": "2019-04-09 17:05:01",
"comments": []
}
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was occurred just because I did a minor mistake writing migration...
There was mismatch of data type in migration and in my database.

I specified my status id as string in comments table, where the model defines it as integer. So it wasn't matched. Changing to integer the one in comments table solved the problem.